# Hide TextBlock.Inlines

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to hide an inlined text within TextBlock?

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
   <Run Text="A" />
   <Run Text="B" />
   <Run Text="" />
   <Run Text="C" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

Even though there is no text between B and C letters, it takes some place which I don't want. I want to hide this inline. How can I do this?

Is there any other way to combine multiple text styles in one line?

Comment: Why do you have an inline if you don't want it?

Comment: Is this an issue where you have "B C" instead of "BC"?

Comment: @H.B. The empty inline has a Name and can be filled with text from code behind.

Comment: @Kendall Frey: Yes, I get "B C", and I want "BC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result isn't because of the extra `Run`. It's just because you have whitespace in the XAML. Doing this should fix it:

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
   <Run Text="A" /><Run Text="B" /><Run Text="" /><Run Text="C" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/5f37aa29-3dc6-44db-9784-197f221f80f7